# ¿Cómo se puede obtener el nombre de la impresora predeterminada con php o javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Quiero saber como obtener el nombre de la impresora predeterminada para imprimir un ticket sin necesidad de poner el nombre de la impresora directo en el codigo o traerlo desde una base de datos

Comment: dale un vistazo a [JsprinterManager](https://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/JSPrintManager4.0/articles/jsprintmanager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mira la librería de printer en JavaScript aquí te dejo un ejemplo básico:

```
var printer = require('printer');
var defaultPrinterName = printer.getDefaultPrinterName();
console.log(defaultPrinterName);
```

Comment: Dónde puedo encontrar dicha libreria?